# Need help preventing UIImagePickerController rotating my portrait-only UIView in IOS13

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an app where i'm making a UIView to take and upload images. My app is portrait only, has been for years, configured with "**supported interface orientations**" in my info.plist.

My problem is this, and it only happens on my iPhone 11 on IOS 13, NOT on my iphone7 running ios12.

1. My view is showing in portrait, like my views always do.
2. I have a button that opens up a `UIPickerViewController` like this:

   ```
   UIImagePickerController *picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];

   picker.delegate = self;

   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

   [self presentViewController:picker animated:true completion:nil];
   ```

If i then turn the camera to landscape, then take a picture OR press cancel, my UIView that previously was in portrait is now in landscape! It obviously looks super strange.

As soon as i put it in portrait, it pops back firmly in place.

Again, it only seems to happen on IOS13, but i have no idea how to solve it.

I have tried overriding **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** in my UIView, it didn't help.

See below for screenshot of how it looks after the camera has rotated it.

Anybody have any thoughts?? Pointers much appreciated.

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

Custom a viewcontroller inherited UIImagePickerController, and overriding `shouldAutorotate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this class:

```
class CustomUIImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController {

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```